# If I grant someone read-only access to a Azure DevOps Repo, can I prevent them from copy and pasting source

Tags: azure-devops, visual-studio-2017

We need to grant someone read-only access to some repos in Visual Studio 2019. Is it possible to stop them from copying and pasting code from within VS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, of course not. There's also no way from stopping them from taking pictures of their screen, or transcribing code onto paper. And while rare, there are also people with eidetic memory.

Don't give someone access to your code if you don't want them to be able to see your code. Unauthorized copying can be handled via the legal system; consult a legal professional licensed to practice law in your jurisdiction.